# 5G NR standards equation

Tags: fft

I'm currently working on the implementation of PRACH decoder for 5G NR. There are certain standards specified by 3GPP and we need to implement our module according to those standards. There is this particular equation that generates a continuous-time domain signal as the output, when fed with discrete frequency domain samples.

From what I understand, this equation depicts the entire process, starting from mapping symbols onto an OFDM grid to generating an analog signal.The antenna takes latter as the input.

The parameter LRA is 139, which is the length of my sequence. I sample the continuous time domain signal at a rate of 122.88MSPS , which gives me 8544 samples.The 122880 samples, are number of samples in a subframe of data. These 8544 PRACH time domain samples , are a part of these 122880 samples.

At the receiver, I receive these 122880 samples, extract my 8544 PRACH samples and perform the decoding operation.

Now, I need to implement the inverse of the standards equation, (shown in the picture below). , which takes in 8544 samples as input and gives out 139 frequency domain samples as output .

At the transmitter, the equation takes in frequency domain samples of length 139 and produces 8544 time domain samples as output.

At the receiver, the inverse of the equation should take 8544 samples and produce frequency domain samples of length 139.

Can anyone help me with finding the inverse of this equation?

[image]

Comment: "The antenna takes latter as the input.", nope, that's the baseband signal representaton of the RF signal that an antenna can deal with. You'll need a IQ DAC, quadrature mixer, amplifiers and filters in front of the antenna :)

Comment: But the main issue I have here: You know that $s_l^{(p,\mu)}$ is an OFDM signal, so you'll need to implement a *full* OFDM receiver to get that data. That's more than inverting a formula; it involves presence detection, time, rate and frequency synchronization and some kind of subchannel coefficient estimation. I.e., an OFDM receiver.